# p value and number of predictors

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, p-value

I was going through the **An Introduction to Statistical Learning: With Applications in R** book and I am facing a bit of difficulty in understanding the below paragraph.I am including the paragraph itself because I do not want to tamper with the original information.

> consider an example in which p = 100 and H0 : β1 = β2 =. . . = βp = 0 is true, so no variable is truly associated with the response. In
> this situation, about 5% of the p-values associated with each variable will be below 0.05 by chance. In other words,
> we expect to see approximately five small p-values even in the absence of
> any true association between the predictors and the response. In fact, we
> are almost guaranteed that we will observe at least one p-value below 0.05
> by chance! Hence, if we use the individual t-statistics and associated pvalues
> in order to decide whether or not there is any association between
> the variables and the response, there is a very high chance that we will
> incorrectly conclude that there is a relationship. However, the F-statistic
> does not suffer from this problem because it adjusts for the number of
> predictors. Hence, if H0 is true, there is only a 5% chance that the Fstatistic
> will result in a p-value below 0.05, regardless of the number of
> predictors or the number of observations.

**I am not able to comprehend the relationship between p values and predictors**.I tried searching also but everywhere the explanation is regarding p value and sample size only.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph adresses the problem of multiple testing, and discusses why we cannot just do $p = 100$ individual hypothesis tests with $H_0: \beta_k = 0$ for each individual predictor at the significance level $\alpha = 0.05$. Even if the null hypothesis is true there is still a chance that the specific $\hat{\beta}_k$ calculated from your sample leads to a rejection of $H_0$. The probability of rejecting $H_0$ even if it is true is equal to your significance level. So, in the example from the paragraph with 100 hypothesis tests and a significance level of 5%, the expected number of rejections is $0.05 \times 100 = 5$, even if all null hypotheses are true (assuming independence). And, as stated in the paragraph, the probability of observing at least one p-value below 0.05 is close to 1. If the multiple testing is not adjusted for, you will falsely conclude that there is evidence in your data at a 5% significance level of relation between predictor and response.

The paragraph then suggest using the $F$-statistic instead, and simultaneously test all $\beta_k$'s.